# Primefaces: dataTable applying patch

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

How can i apply a patch to my PrimeFaces dataTable. Here is the patch that i want to apply: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3608

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find the PF sources here: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/checkout. Check out the sources and apply your patch file (using [patch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch). If you are new to patch you may find useful this quick guide: [The Ten Minute Guide to diff and patch](http://jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html)). Finally build and include the resulting jar within your project.

Comment: everything seems clear but re-building the PrimeFaces source codes gives lots of errors have you ever tried?

Comment: sure. when we started to develop with PrimeFaces I wrote some trivial patches to the chart components. Since PrimeFaces is a maven project all the required dependencies should be downloaded during the build.